# Samsung Galaxy S shuts down automatically

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s

I'm using Samsung Galaxy S i9003. I used it for 1 years. Recently when I want to start apps the phone automatically shuts down. The battery is fully charged. Anyone faced it before?

I'm running Android 2.2 froyo
Sometimes it takes 3/4 mins of app launch to automatically shut the phone

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: if the phone is connected to charge then it never shuts down

Comment: Does it happens with every app you launch?

Comment: yes, it happens with every app I launched.

Comment: You should try upgrading your Firmware and/or Factory Reset (Backup!!) that should solve it if it's a software problem.

Comment: my be it was a hardware problem, Changing battery to a new one solved the problem